# diff, date_diff, abs - Cálculo de datas em PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde a todos, há plugins tanto no Javascript quanto no PHP para cálculo de datas, eu como não sabia calcular durações no PHP optava por fazer este trabalho no javascript mesmo e postar o resultado já calculado.
Há pouco tempo pesquisei o assunto como sou iniciante e entendo pouco o inglês não consegui nada rápido que me explicaria como calcular a duração entre duas datas e inserir o resultado no banco de dados. Obviamente vim aqui, realizei o questionamento e em pouco obtive exito, até sabia que no PHP existia o `.diff()` e o `.date_diff()` mas não sabia do `.abs()`.

**Exemplo:**

```
$date1 = strtotime($_POST['data_inicio']);
$date2 = strtotime($_POST['data_fim']);
$duracao = date('H:i:s', abs( $date2 - $date1 ));
```

*Como não sabia do `abs()` estava tentando fazer isso com `diff()`.

Esquecendo os Plugins e pensando no PHP puro ainda sim gostaria de algo mais abrangente sobre este assunto, e em português:

Quais os métodos de cada um? Quando devo usa-los ? Há outras funções para cálculos de datas ou duração no PHP?.

PS.: Se esse assunto for muito simples me desculpem, podem postar link de algo já pronto, ou se a pergunta for desnecessária pode ser excluída.

Obrigado desde Já.

Comment: Você quer saber quando usar cada um deles?

Comment: Isso, como cada um funciona e se há outras opções.

Comment: abs não é para calcular data, ele é para tornar um valor absoluto, por exemplo um resultado de uma conta que gera valor negativo é convertido para positivo, a diferença entre usar o date+strtotime+abs e o DateTime::diff é simplesmente facilitar, basicamente você escolhe o que preferir, mas só deve ter que entender que a classe DateTime foi criada para facilitar trabalhar com datas, evitando ter que escrever calculos ou conversões "manulamente".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Definição**

[**`diff`**](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/diff-implementation/): É o termo utilizado para fazer a comparação.

[**`date_diff`**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-diff.php): Esta função é um apelido para: [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.diff.php). Retorna a diferença entre dois objetos `DateTime`.

```
<?php
   $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
   $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
   $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
   echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

[**`abs`**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.abs.php): Retorna o valor absoluto. Com relação a datas, você pode criar uma série de datas começando com o primeiro dia da semana para cada semana, se você deseja preencher uma lista na sua página web com esta data matemática. Use a função `abs()` para converter números negativos gerados a partir de datas no passado.

```
<?php
   $TwoWeeksAgo = new DateTime(date("Ymd"));
   $TwoWeeksAgo->sub(new DateInterval('P'.abs ( (7-date("N")-14)).'D'));
   $LastWeek = new DateTime(date("Ymd"));
   $LastWeek->sub(new DateInterval('P'.abs ( (7-date("N")-7)).'D'));
   $ThisWeek = new DateTime(date("Ymd"));
   $ThisWeek->add(new DateInterval('P'.abs ( (7-date("N"))).'D'));

   echo 'Start of This week is '.$ThisWeek->format('l m/d/Y').'<br/>';
   echo 'Start of Last week is '.$LastWeek->format('l m/d/Y').'<br/>';
   echo 'Start of 2 weeks ago is '.$TwosWeekAgo->format('l m/d/Y').'<br/>';
?>
```

**Trabalhando com datas**

Aconselho a ver essa [parte](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.datetime.php) da documentação.

**Data atual formatada**: Função sem parâmetro que retorna a data no formato desejado.

```
function data(){
    return date('d/m/Y', time());
}
```

**Formatar data**: O jeito mais prático de converter uma data de um formato para o outro.

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

**Pegar o número da semana**: Se precisar saber o número de uma semana, passe a data como parâmetro desta função.

```
function weeknumber($ddate){
    $date = new DateTime($ddate);
    return $date->format("W");
}
```

**Converter minutos em horas**: Informe os minutos que a função retornará o valor em horas, e minutos se necessário.

```
function convertToHoursMins($time, $format = '%02d:%02d') {
    if ($time < 1) {
        return;
    }
    $hours = floor($time / 60);
    $minutes = ($time % 60);
    return sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes);
}
```

**Diferença entre duas datas**: Esta função retorna a diferença de tempo entre duas datas em horas e minutos.

```
function dateDiff($date1, $date2){
        $datetime1 = new DateTime($date1);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($date2);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    return $interval->format('%H:%I');
}
```

**Data no passado ou futuro?** Lista de condições para saber se uma data está no passado, presente ou futuro.

```
if(strtotime(dateString) > time()) {
     # futuro
}

if(strtotime(dateString) < time()) {
     # passado
}

if(strtotime(dateString) == time()) {
     # presente
}
```

**Calcular idade**: Informando uma data como parâmetro, você consegue saber a idade.

```
function age($date){
    $time = strtotime($date);
    if($time === false){
      return '';
    }

    $year_diff = '';
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $time);
    list($year,$month,$day) = explode('-',$date);
    $year_diff = date('Y') - $year;
    $month_diff = date('m') - $month;
    $day_diff = date('d') - $day;
    if ($day_diff < 0 || $month_diff < 0) $year_diff-;

    return $year_diff;
}
```

**Dias entre duas datas**: Uma lista dos dias entre duas datas especificadas por você.

```
// Estabeleça o fuso horário
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$start_date = new DateTime('2010-10-01');
$end_date = new DateTime('2010-10-05');

$period = new DatePeriod(
    $start_date, // 1st PARAM: start date
    new DateInterval('P1D'), // 2nd PARAM: interval (1 day interval in this case)
    $end_date, // 3rd PARAM: end date
    DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE // 4th PARAM (optional): self-explanatory
);

foreach($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d').'<br/>'; // Display the dates in yyyy-mm-dd format
}
```

**Contagem regressiva até uma data**: Código rápido para saber quanto tempo, em dias e horas, até uma determinada data.

```
$dt_end = new DateTime('December 3, 2016 2:00 PM');
$remain = $dt_end->diff(new DateTime());
echo $remain->d . ' days and ' . $remain->h . ' hours';
```

Answer (score 2):

Alguns detalhes:

- `abs()` não é para calcular data, ele é para tornar um valor absoluto, por exemplo um resultado de uma conta que gera valor negativo é convertido para positivo
- `DateTime` não é um plugin, é uma classe nativa

O problema ali foi resolvido com `abs()` porque eventualmente algumas datas de fim no seu form talvez vinham com valor vazio ou valor menor que a data de inicio, então aquele calculo seu foi feio de forma manual.

*Então*, a diferença entre usar o `date`+`strtotime`+`abs` e o `DateTime::diff` é simplesmente facilitar, basicamente você escolhe o que preferir, mas só deve ter que entender que a classe `DateTime` foi criada para facilitar trabalhar com datas, evitando ter que escrever cálculos ou conversões "manualmente"

Resumindo `DateTime` faz várias coisas, todas focadas em trabalhar o tempo, o que facilita bastante, agora ao usar somente `date()` ou `gmdate()` terá que ajustar muita coisa e fazer de maneira manual.